# rspec stub record query

Tags: ruby, rspec, stub

I am trying to stub the results from query to retrieve some records.  Here is the query:

```
ouid = OrganizationalUnit.where("billing_id = ? AND status = 'active'", data[:billing_id]).select(:id)
user_id = User.where("group_id in (14,17) AND organizational_unit_id in (?) AND status = 'active'", ouid).select(:id).first
```

I am trying to stub it with this:

```
    ou_value = double'fake ou',{ 'id' => '654321' }
    select_double = double 'fake select', {'select' => [ou_value]}
    OrganizationalUnit.stub( :where).and_return(select_double)
```

This isn't working. My query to user table looks like this:

```
SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE (group_id in (14,17) AND organizational_unit_id in ('--- !ruby/object:RSpec::Mocks::Mock\n__null_object: false\nname: fake ou\noptions:\n :__declared_as: Double\n') AND status = 'active') LIMIT 1
```

where it should look like this:

```
SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE (group_id in (14,17) AND organizational_unit_id in (654321) AND status = 'active') LIMIT 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you want to stub this query:

```
OrganizationalUnit.where("billing_id = ? AND status = 'active'", data[:billing_id]).select(:id)
```

i think this should be

```
OrganizationalUnit.stub_chain(:where, :select).and_return(654321)
```

another thing: it's always a good idea to move finders within methods or scopes in the model. by doing this it is even easier to stub or mock stuff for testing.